# Foul Psychology Question

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, english

According to our psychology examination, Mr. X

> - Is afraid of heights as well as the cookie monster under his bed (1)
> - Prefers to work late into the night (2)
> - Has 20/20 vision with perfect visual acuity (2)
> - Prefers pacifism to conflict and will do anything to avoid a fight (1)
> - Gave a fantastic farewell performance at Carnegie Hall before giving up music for medicine (2)

Based on these results, for tonight's formal dinner, should we serve Mr. X

> **A)** A heady and fragrant coconut cauliflower curry, lightly spiced and served on a fluffy bed of steaming, pearly white rice
>   **B)** Decadent foie gras, perfectly seared, served with fresh sourdough bread, and accompanied by a sweet and tart fruit salad
>   **C)** I don't know

**Note:** The author of this examination claims no expertise over writing appetizing culinary descriptions

Comment: Well... C seems right to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure, but it looks like Mr. X may be...

> **a bird**.
>
>  - Is afraid of heights as well as the cookie monster under his bed (1), because he is a **chicken**.
>  - Prefers to work late into the night (2) because he is a **night owl**.
>  - Has 20/20 vision with perfect visual acuity (2) because he is **hawk-eyed**/**eagle-eyed**.
>  - Prefers pacifism to conflict and will do anything to avoid a fight (1) because he is a **dove**. 
>  - Gave a fantastic farewell performance at Carnegie Hall before giving up music for medicine (2) which was his **swan song**? Not sure if the medicine part is important.

The title...

> may be some kind of foul/fowl pun?

What should we serve Mr. X?

> probably not foie gras, since that's close to cannibalism, but I don't know what would make A the correct answer, so... I don't know?